# arrays in for loops...what am i doing wrong?

Tags: arrays, gjs

ok
my problem
im trying to manually parse a xml into an array of arrays (dont know exactly the terminology)
so my code is similar to this

```
gjs> var f=[],g=[];
for (j=1;j<5;j++){
for(s=1;s<5;s++){g[s]=Math.random()}
f[j]=g;
log(f[j]);
}
```

and the result is this

gjs> .... .... .... .... typein:2: strict warning: assignment to undeclared variable j
typein:3: strict warning: assignment to undeclared variable s
      JS LOG: ,0.14567040192803105,0.08676287513204084,0.9227891041751024,0.8698835169518646
      JS LOG: ,0.18009167591958863,0.9074902809032479,0.9244884012106213,0.39937741495685974
      JS LOG: ,0.6942042873840697,0.4262341598548133,0.398151943992746,0.36844997948987923
      JS LOG: ,0.9064724340409265,0.5317808160966455,0.019482062746835505,0.06796944552969397

gjs> f[**1**]
,0.9064724340409265,0.5317808160966455,0.019482062746835505,0.06796944552969397
gjs> f[2]
,0.9064724340409265,0.5317808160966455,0.019482062746835505,0.06796944552969397
gjs> f[3]
,0.9064724340409265,0.5317808160966455,0.019482062746835505,0.06796944552969397
gjs> f[4]
,0.9064724340409265,0.5317808160966455,0.019482062746835505,0.06796944552969397

now the problem is that f array has same array on all elements and i really have no idea what im doing wrong here.
this is just an example. but i have exactly same problem with my code.i must be doing something wrong but i really have no idea what. i what each element from f to have the g array that has been generated when inserted into f. do i make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the same array **g**. You are always changing its elements and all elements of **f** point to the same **g** array.

This should fix it:

```
var f=[];
for (j=1;j<5;j++){
var g = []
for(s=1;s<5;s++){g[s]=Math.random()}
f[j]=g;
log(f[j]);
}
```

Notice, now there is a new **g** declaration for each **j** iteration.

Comment: ok that fixed my problem. thank you. i think i understand what u said but im confused also. i thought that F will get the values from g not the variable itself. well another thing to remember :)

Comment: Variables usually hold only the reference to an array, not the array itself. Some types are "reference types" (like arrays and objects) and others are "value types" (like int and other primitives).

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you must declare `f` as multi-dimensional array.

The code must look like,

```
gjs> var f=[][],g=[];
for (j=1;j<5;j++){
for(s=1;s<5;s++){g[s]=Math.random()}
f[j]=g;
log(f[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, taking this step by step and actually explaining what happens seems like the best approach. I see @Boyko Karadzhov gave an answer that fulfilled the task but there seems to be a lack of explanation.
First off, assuming this code is supposed to be ES6 compatible, try not to use `var` if you don't need the variable to be available in the global code space. `let` is bound to scopes, thus declaring any variable you need in multiple places at the top of your code is a cleaner solution, which prevents conflicts when another variable with the same name exists in the code of e.g. a Shell Extension.

Another issue is the warning about using undeclared variables that may cause issues if the code has to be run in strict mode. This code runs because it's not in strict mode. If it was, it would error and stop instead. This warning comes from the looping variables `j` and `s` which are not declared, but used as if they already exist.

Last but not least, you're allocating resources to create array `g` just to push that into `f` later, instead of setting the values of `f` to arrays so the allocated resources only increase when required.

```js
// Initialize the variable you'll be populating in the loop
let f = [];

// Set up the loop without causing warnings
// Use a let so the variable only exists within the loop
// Set s to 0 because arrays have a 0-based index. That means the first element will be f[0]
for(let s = 0; s < 4; s++){
    // Rather than using resources to create g, add an array to f immediately
    f[s] = []; // This is the same as your f[s] = g, but values get added later and
               // it doesn't create the extra variable
    // Populate f[s] in another loop
    while(f[s].length < 5){
        // Add a random value to f[s] at a new position
        f[s].push(Math.random());
    }
    // Log the values as you did before.
    log(f[s]);
}
```

The reason the `for` is used in the outer loop is because there's an actual need for `s` to be used. as it is required to at least check how many entries there are in the array `f[s]`. It is completely redundant to use the index in the inner loop, as the only purpose it serves is adding elements to the end of an array. This can be done based on the simple boolean check of the array's `length` property rather than counting.